# get two characters from different locations using php

Tags: php

I've values in database

`Buyer` `Client` `Shipper` `Consignee` `Forwarding Agent` `Notification Company`

I want `BU` from buyer `SH` from shipper `CN` from consignee `FA` from forwarding agent and `NC` from notification company with the help of PHP language so how could I achieve this? Right now I'm getting full name so I want two characters from different locations.

Comment: Those are column names?? I dont get it sorry or location means different tables ?

Comment: Those are values not column name.

Comment: why not take another column in database to store short name values as well?

Comment: Agree with @MageshKumaar Will help to give answer if you can explain the context and flow of your problem more in detail. From where and how do you get these values and where do you want to generate these 2 characters

Comment: you can use `substr($string,start,end)` Like `substr("BUYER",0,2)`?? And again I don't get it   !?

Comment: No I can't take another column name.

Comment: all other following pattern means `Buyer` = 'BU' (if single word than first 2 latter) and  `Notification Company` = 'NC' (first char if word more then 2), but `Consignee` = 'CN' (what is pattern for this???)

Comment: Better if you use mysql query to achieve this

Comment: `substr("BUYER",0,2)` this will work with `buyer` `client` `shipper` except `consignee` `forwarding agent` and `notification company`.

Comment: how I use mysql query fro this?

Comment: On you mean like`$string="consignee"` now you can use `echo $string[0].$string[2]` ? to display first and third character ?

Comment: I'm returning complete column name like this `$rsLevels["levelTitle"]` so I could use `$rsLevels["levelTitle"][0]` and `$rsLevels["levelTitle"][3]` like this because this levelTitle field name is in function and at last I use `return` keyword `$rsLevels["levelTitle"]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $myLoc = "Consignee";  // put your character...
$words = explode(" ",$myLoc);
count($words);
if($myLoc == "Consignee"){
$acronym = $myLoc{0}.$myLoc{2};
}
else if( count($words) >1){
    $acronym = "";

    foreach ($words as $w) {
      $acronym .= $w[0];
    }
    }else{
    $acronym = substr($myLoc, 0,2);
    } 
  echo  $acronym;
 ?>
```

Comment: @user3833682 : what is the issue.beco'z it's perfectly working for me

Comment: I'm saying the function is ok but problem with `Consignee` value I want `CN` from `Consignee` not `CO`.

Comment: @user3833682  : just remove this "echo" from "echo count($words);"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
function getAcronym($word){
    $word = trim($word);
    if(strpos($word," ") >0){
        $acronym = strtoupper(substr($word,0,1).substr($word,strpos($word," ")+1,1));
    } else{
        $acronym = strtoupper(substr($word,0,2));
    }

    return $acronym;
}

print_r(getAcronym("Buyer")); // Gives BU
print_r(getAcronym("Notification Company")); // Gives NC
```

However for Consingment it will return CO an not CN as you mentioned. If you need specific characters for each word and not according to a single rule, you can either use a separate table where you can store Two characters short forms for each term and look up the table when required.

Comment: I'm getting this `BU CL SH FA NC` except `Consignee` `CN`, for `Consignee` its giving me `CO`.

Comment: your function is working correctly but problem in `Consignee`.

Comment: Just store the column name in a variable.
Example : `$string=$rsLevels["levelTitle"]` ( assume this returns consignee) then store the characters in another variable `$revised_string=strtoupper($string[0].$string[2])`

Comment: @user3833682 Please read the bottom Para in my answer. That already mentions about 'Consignment', basically meant 'Consignee'